# I want to Thread and Form work together

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronize

I want to run my `Thread` then run application instruction. why run all after `Sleep`?
I have a `TQuery`(it has many record and slow fetch) instead `Sleep` and when `Open`, `Thread` no run before `Open` `TQuery`.
`ShowMessage` and `Sleep` are for test.
What's solution?

```
  TCustomThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure doProc;
  end;
.
.
.
procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(doProc);
end;

procedure TCustomThread.doProc;
begin
  ShowMessage('Thread');
end;
.
.
.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  thrd : TCustomThread;
begin
  thrd := TCustomThread.Create(True);
  thrd.Resume;
  Sleep(3000);
  ShowMessage('Form');
end;
```

Comment: I know that English is not your first language, but it is still the case that your question is unclear. You have to try to edit it and make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking why your "ShowMessage('Thread');" doesn't execute until after the code in your Button1Click handler has finished?

Comment: Please read more into how to create threads before asking why it's not working as planned.

Comment: Yes, my first lang isn't eng! Thanks

Comment: I asking about work Thread when main Form is busy.

Comment: I read many sites about Thread but i don't know when use a large Table why Thread not work correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Button1Click` is stopping the execution of the main thread for 3 seconds.

During the `sleep(3000)` execution, no GDI message is processed, so the dialog boxes are NOT displayed immediately.

In fact, `TCustomThread.doProc` works as expected, but the dialog box is not displayed until the GDI messages are processed.

You have to change this method e.g. into:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  thrd : TCustomThread;
  expectedEnd: TDateTime;
begin
  thrd := TCustomThread.Create(True);
  thrd.Resume;
  expectedEnd := Now+(1/24/60/60*3); 
  repeat
    Sleep(50); // or any long process
    Application.ProcessMessages; // to be called to process the GDI messages
  until Now>=expectedEnd;
  ShowMessage('Form');
end;
```

In short: never use `Sleep()` in the main GDI thread, for extended period of time (more than some ms), otherwise your application won't be responsive any more. And Windows will complain for it and ask you to kill the application!

So in your case, you have to call `Application.ProcessMessages` in your main thread when a long process is taken place (e.g. a `TQuery`), or run the query in a background thread (this is IMHO the preferred method), as we do e.g. for our [Open Source mORMot framework on client side](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/07/04/Let-mORmot-s-applications-be-even-more-responsive).

Comment: Neither + or - 1, good explanation, but `Application.ProcessMessages` usually also means poor design - it's just flat out dangerous to use.

Comment: @JerryDodge Application.ProcessMessages always means poor design.

Comment: You don't mean GDI messages. There's no such thing. Terminology is a little loose.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes, indeed - this is why I spoke about the proposal of using a dedicated background thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right: this is not the right term. But why on earth every time I go back to SO, and try to help, there is such a crusade and trolling about the questions and the answers? We are here to help, aren't we? Even a compiler with aggressive warnings/hints settings would be more open-minded and accept a relaxed syntax. :) Once again, I'm fed up with this spirit. If I did have the same behavior with the people on my support forums, I would probably have never anyone willing to contribute to my Open Source projects. Perhaps I'll go back in the next weeks. Am I wasting my time?

Comment: Sorry but where is the crusade and trolling?

Comment: I'm feeding the troll

Comment: It would be easier to fix the terminology and let me delete my comment. What's the problem with that? No trolling.

Comment: Perhaps you'll object to this comment too. But the reason that the message from the thread is not getting displayed is really that the call to Synchronize blocks on the main threads sleeps. It is not that ShowMessage is called but the messages needed to service that don't get through. It is that ShowMessage is not called because that has to happen on the main thread which is asleep.

Comment: I find it offensive that you resort to personal abuse. Name calling is not acceptable. I feel it is not unreasonable to comment on the factual accuracy of an answer. Yes it is good that you are trying to help. Of course. But the fact that your intentions are good does not make what you say correct. Fundamentally though I strongly object to name calling and personal abuse.

Comment: I only just looked at the code.  I am just apalled that this A.PM Sleep() loop answer got accepted.

Comment: @Martin Especially when you look at the asker's subsequent question. Asker has taken from this answer a recommendation to use `ProcessMessages`.

Comment: Why did some proud anonymous downvoters click on -1 with no comment? :-(

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to be

> Why does the form message appear before the thread message?

Simply put, your use of `Synchonize` means that all the code executes on the main thread. This means that the first message box must wait for the second message box to complete.

So, why does the form message box show first? The `Synchronize` method is used from threads to invoke code on the main thread. This `Synchronize` method signals the main thread that there is work to be done and then blocks until the main thread can do it.

The main thread won't start this work whilst it is busy in an event handler as your program is. So the call to `Sleep` actually blocks both threads because both threads are waiting on the main thread.

So to re-cap, the `Synchronize` method blocks until the main thread completes the work described in the procedure passed to `Synchronize`. If the main thread is busy then `Synchronize` blocks until the main thread completes its busy tasks.

---

Looking more broadly at your question you describe long running database tasks happening on the main thread. There is the fundamental problem. You must not have those tasks on the main thread. The main thread is dedicated to serving the GUI. That requires it to be responsive at all times and be able to service its message queue. Putting long running tasks on the main thread will destroy your GUI. Put those tasks on worker threads away from the main thread.

I suspect that you are using `Synchronize` because you've realised that the GUI is unresponsive because of your database code. And you reason that you can use a thread to keep the GUI responsive. But that can never work. The main thread must process messages in a timely manner. If the database code does not do so then you cannot service the message queue from the outside. There has to be co-operation.

The bottom line here is that long-running tasks must execute away from the main thread.